# Outlook 2010 not able to access Exchange 2010 GAL

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, exchange-2010, outlook-2010

When a user (including me) clicks the to box on a new email outlook hangs for about a min then brings up the Select Names dialog. When you perform a search the "New Mail" dialog along with the Select Names hangs, but not outlook main.

A message pops up from the task bar that outlook is trying to retrieve data from the exchange server. [Screen shot here](http://screencast.com/t/TIaYiP1Z1)

After several minuts an error box appears "The search cannont be completed. The operation failed." [Screen shot here](http://screencast.com/t/p7gkJmzIjjlI)

I've tried rebooting the Domain Controllers and the Exchange CAS and Mail store servers, but that didn't change anything.

Also the domain is a 2008 R2 functional level.

Thank you for your time,

Kerry

Comment: Troubleshooting ideas: 1) test with OWA, 2) look for application event log errors on the Exchange servers, 3) when did it last work fine and did anything change?

Comment: OWA ERROR   Exception type: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADTransientException
Exception message: An RPC exception occurred while reading the member count of an address list. The error is "Error 0x6d9 (There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper)

Comment: It worked fine yesterday, and nothing got changed overnight.

Comment: Possible help: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrclients/thread/e3f2a5c8-74b1-4e09-ba37-cb08eb2510ca .  All Exchange services are started fine on the Exchange servers?  Can you open a case with MS support on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that a subdomain of our AD had a problem replicating with our primary domain. After fixing this on their end, everything was ok.

Answer (score 1):

My gut is saying that something is filtering the traffic between the client and the Exchange Server computer. If you run a `netstat -a -n` while the first message is displayed do you see any connections stuck in a `SYN_SENT` state?

(An aside: I'd rather be in Macon makin' bacon.)